# Which model to use for multiple outputs in classification problem

Tags: classification, python, categorical-data, multi-class, multilabel

I want to predict `roles` based on `name, experience, soft skills, technical skills` . Based on all these variables I want to predict `Roles` now the roles predicted should be 2 or 1 or may be 5 etc. based on the input variables.

Can someone give me some insight how can I approach this type of problem.

Variable `Role` has 16000 unique values each observation has one role. (but I want to predict similar Roles based on input data) (Prediction)

`Technical Skills` are categorical (can apply TF-IDF)

`Soft Skills` (can apply TF-IDF).

`Average experience`(numerical) can apply binning method.

Comment: Each row has only 1 role but while predicting it should predict n roles based on the input data.

Comment: What do you mean exactly and is this data something like a list of people with their skills/experience and what role they currently have, or an assessment of people for different roles and the rating of their suitability? Do you want to predict the most likely role a person with these characteristics in the data (just the class) or the probability such a person has such a role (probability for each class)? Or something else? Are all the features high-cardinality categorical values (or multiple ones), too, or are they e.g. numerical scores? Are there multiple rows per Name?

Comment: @Björn Yes this data has a list of people with their skills/experience, name and each observation has only 1 Job Role. As you mentioned I want to predict the most likely top 5 (or 1, 2, 3, 7, etc.) roles a person with these characteristics can have (just the class). Each observation has unique names. I have edited my question with variable details.

Comment: @10sha25 So just to be clear: you have a dataset with a target variable (`Role`) that has 16k unique values (16k different classes)? And you want to be able to predict the most likely roles for each person?

Comment: @AdriàLuz Yes, right

Comment: @Björn  please tell me if you have some insight on this

Comment: My first guess would be that a neural network (like the two-layer default model in fastai see https://docs.fast.ai/tabular.learner.html) could be a good idea because of the high cardinality categorical feature(s), because these might get represented quite well by embedding layer(s).